# CSS Styling for boxed border floating to right (and preferrebly next to the cursor) corner

Tags: html, css, hover, border

As per title, I have got the code almost working I think, but due to having limited knowledge on CSS, I am making stupid mistakes/assumptions. Any help with explanation would be much appreciated.

The fiddle link is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8utvjfm8/)

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background: #ffffff;
}
ul li {
  color: #0000ff;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 21px;
  text-align: left;
}
ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 25px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 140px;
}
ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
ul li ul.dropdown {
  min-width: 125px;
  /* Set width of the dropdown */
  background: #f2f2f2;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  left: 500;
}
ul li:hover ul.dropdown {
  border: 2px solid #0000ff;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 50px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
ul li:hover a:hover ul.dropdown {}
```

```html
<div id="mylinks">
  <ul id="mylists" href="#">
    <li><a href="#">MY LIST MENU</a>

      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#"><span id="level1" onclick="location.href='http://www.google.co.uk/'" title="Go Google"> First item<span> </a> 
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"> Second item </a> 
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Sir,That Fiddle is empty..

Comment: @Vijay                Updated the link:)

Comment: Got it sir,,Please wait.I will try to help you

Comment: What changes you want to make it,sir.Please brief

Comment: @Vijay           The title was the question/requirement itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a correct position for the dropdown list:

```
ul li ul.dropdown {
  min-width: 125px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  left: 150px;
  top: 0;
}
```

Notice that left was set to 150px and top was set to 0.